# Matrix associated of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I solve the following exercise?

Let $V$ be the vector space defined on the field $\mathbb{R}$ of $n-$dimensional. Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^{n-1}\neq 0$, $T^{n}= 0$ and  $B=\left \{ x,T\left ( x \right ),T^{2}\left ( x \right ),\cdots ,T^{n-1}\left ( x \right ) \right \}$ it is a basis for $V$. Find a matrix associated with the linear transformation $T$.

I think the only way to explicitly determine the matrix associated with the linear transformation $T$, is to define $T$ as $T\left ( \alpha _{1}x+\alpha _{2}T\left ( x \right ) +\cdots +\alpha _{n-1}T^{n-1}\left ( x \right )\right )=\alpha _{1}x+\alpha _{2}T\left ( x \right ) +\cdots +\alpha _{n-1}T^{n-1}\left ( x \right )$.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
T[\alpha_1 x + \alpha_2 T(x) + \cdots + \alpha_n T^{n-1}(x)] = \alpha_{1}T(x) + \alpha_2 T^2(x) + \cdots + \alpha_{n-1}T^{n-1}(x)
$$
To put it another way: if we rewrite $B$ as $B = \{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$, then we have
$$
T[\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n] = \alpha_{1}v_2 + \alpha_2 v_3 + \cdots + \alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}
$$
Thus, the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $V$ is
$$
\pmatrix{0&0&0&\cdots & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots &1& 0 & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0}
$$